# Run a function without executing its print() statements

Tags: r

I wrote a function that outputs a single element numeric after a 300-cycle `for` loop. I make it print about 10 lines in each cycle, to know where it's at. Now I want to run this `for` loop itself in a 1000 cycle `for` loop (and place the resulting numbers in a matrix). But it prints way to much stuff and I don't know where it's at in the execution of the outer (1000 cycle) `for` loop.  The output from the inner `for` loop overwhelms a print statement executed at each of the outer loop's cycles. Here's how it looks:

```
for(i in 1:1000){
   function(...){...} #prints 10 lines 300 times before outputting a single element numeric
   cat("Outer loop step "); print(i)}
```

Now I don't want to remove the print statements from my function, but I want to mute them when I call the function in that `for` loop. How can I run my function without executing it's print() statements?

Comment: @jdharrison This doesn't work, check it out at the command prompt: > 2
[prints 2]
> invisible(2)
[prints nothing]
> invisible(print(2))
[prints 2]

Answer (score 4):

Modify your function so you can pass in a "debug" true/false parameter to control the print statements.

Comment: How might you do that?

Comment: Add boolean debug parameter to function call, execute print statements within function based on  the setting of the the "debug" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `print` or `cat`. Use `message` instead. You can then use `suppressMessages` to suppress the message output.